# Javascript : Splitting a String into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string which has two sets of values like below...

```
12/31/13_69,01/01/14_30,01/03/14_195,01/07/14_169
```

The first is a date and the second is a value for that date. I basically want to create 2 arrays from this string (for a Highcharts graph). One an array of dates and another an array of values like below...

```
{12/31/13,01/01/14,01/03/14,01/07/14}
{69,30,195,169}
```

Can you please share with me the Javascript code I can use to create this? Some variant of the split function maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to split by `,` and then loop through the results, spliting again by `_`. Or use regex. Don't.

Comment: Give it a try first; then ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
var str   = '12/31/13_69,01/01/14_30,01/03/14_195,01/07/14_169',
    dates = str.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/g),
    vals  = str.match(/\d+(?=,|$)/g);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses, Emissary yours seem the most simple so I decided to go with it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This will first split by a comma, then use a for loop to split by the underscore and assign all of the values to array1 (containing the date) and array2 (containing the date code).

```
var ms = "12/31/13_69,01/01/14_30,01/03/14_195,01/07/14_169"

var arr = ms.split(",")

var array1 = new Array()
var array2 = new Array()

var temp = ""

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    temp=arr[i].split("_")

    array1[i] = temp[0]
    array2[i] = temp[1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to find successive matches.

```
var results = { dates: [], values: [] },
    s = '12/31/13_69,01/01/14_30,01/03/14_195,01/07/14_169',
    regex = /(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})_(\d+),?/g,
    result;

while ((result = regex.exec(s)) !== null) {
    results.dates.push(result[1]);
    results.values.push(result[2]);
}
```